# Best way to create same file structures in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Given a huge EF MVC solution where there are separate projects for data models, services (interfaces and their implementations) and repositories. It is necessary to create new files with given structures, e.g.: different using, namespaces, etc.

**Example**
New database table is created with the following names:

- SomesSession
- SomeQuestions
- SomeAnswers
- SomeScores

Four files under the Models project, four files under Services - Interfaces, four files Services (where implementing the interfaces), four files under Repositories.

Is there or what is the best way to make automatic this tedious task?
Maybe Visual studio macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out-of-the-box Visual Studio templating to generate code on Entity Framework and many other frameworks is implemented using [*T4*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Template_Transformation_Toolkit).

Check this MSDN article to learn more about how to implement these code generation templates from scratch:

- [Code Generation and T4 Text Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Matías, this is what I am looking for. :)

Comment: @Paxsentry No problem, you're welcome!!